# Do thrown eggs deal damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if thrown eggs deal any damage at all, because I remember you had to watch out when throwing eggs into a chicken coop, as you might accidentally kill one of the chickens. However now, I just tested this and it doesn't *seem* to do any damage, even though it *does* do the "hit" animation (they jump and flash red).

I only tested this on a chicken, and I hit it ~30 times (which is more than enough to kill a chicken at half a heart damage per hit), to no avail.

So do thrown eggs deal damage at all? Or is it just chickens?

P.S. I know I could test this on myself, but I don't have access to any other players at the moment, and my redstone skills a dismal at best, so setting up a jig to test it on myself is unlikely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki article on eggs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Egg):

> Players are able to throw eggs at mobs and give the same effect as if the mob were being damaged by a weapon. They deal half a heart to Ender Dragons (except when hit in the head), but no damage to other mobs. Eggs can also be fired from dispensers and are affected by gravity. Throwing eggs at neutral mobs will provoke them.

Comment: So it only deals damage to the Ender Dragon? Curious...

Comment: Eggs no longer deal damage to the ender dragon.

Answer (score -1):

On the Xbox One edition of Minecraft, eggs don't do damage to players, or they have 0 effect but mobs get pushed back, or they act like they're getting hurt. So the way you can use eggs against mob would be to push them back so you don't die.

Comment: sary for terrible spelling

Answer (score -2):

> Players are able to throw eggs and deal knockback to mobs and other players, but no damage will be dealt. Throwing eggs at neutral mobs will provoke them. Eggs can also be fired from dispensers and are affected by gravity.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Egg)

Comment: This is not exactly true. The other (accepted) answer is more accurate and has the exception given already.

Comment: This answer seems to be copy-pasted from this [source](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Egg) cited in another answer or from another source. Please consider next time adding the source to your answer.